# Is it possible to configure "unique" constraints using when Infinispan as a datagrid?

Tags: java, infinispan

I have the following Student class.

```
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private int contestantId;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String contact;
    private String country;
    private String countryCode;
    private String school;

    ...
    A couple more properties as well as getters and setters...
    ...
}
```

My business logic requires that the email and contact number be unique. In the case of a traditional RDMS, I can easily accomplish this by setting the column to `UNIQUE` and handling any Constraint Exceptions that arises.

Due to our hosting environment (OpenShift doesn't scale the database), I would like to convert my existing application from storing data directly in PostgreSQL to using Infinispan's distributed data grid. However, the main issue I have now is that I cannot figure out how to enforce the `UNIQUE` constraints for both the email and contact.

Is there a workaround for my problem or do I have to conclude that Infinispan isn't suited for my particular set of requirements?

Comment: Assuming you're using the map-like API in Infinispan, if the key is encoded with the email and contact number, you could verify if the key is unique by checking if there's an entry with that key already present in the cache. Alternatively, if you don't wanna encode this information in the key, you could use Infinispan Map/Reduce to check if a Student with the same email+contact number is present in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

A datagrid can deliver impressive scalability features **because** every entry is strictly independent. So it doesn't even make sense to think about a "unique" validation, but there are options by reformulating the problem.

- You could use a Cache in which you store your Student data keyed by email, and a second Cache using a key by contact number. Before creating a new entry, you verify it's not existing already. Optionally you could wrap both operations in a transaction, or use *putIfAbsent* operations. In one cache you store the data, in the second cache you could store a copy (if that's useful) or just a marker token, or the key for the other Cache to easily find Students from different properties.
- You could use indexing, so you can search for Students by email / contacts / etc..
- You could use a combination. I would likely use indexing to check before attempting to insert, so I have flexibility on accessing any fields, and don't need to duplicate data or make too unusual mappings, but then at insertion time I would still use a transaction with a *putIfAbsent* operation to make sure a concurrent thread won't attempt to create the same student at the same time.